# angular js dom manipulation with directives

Tags: css, html, dom, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to use angular directives to dynamically replace an html portion of a portlet of a page.

The html portlet has 2 sections embedded. The top part has the heading which is obtained from a different backend service

```
<div class="headerdiv">
<h3 class='headerclass'> <a href="">Object Heading</a> </h3>
</div>
```

The content is loaded in to a different section

```
<div id="objectDiv" ng-controller="ObjectCtrl">
   <div ng-show="object.title" mydirective><b>{{object.title}} </b></div>

   <div element-trigger><b>{{object.name}} </b></div>
   <div element-trigger><b>{{object.description}} </b></div>

 </div>
```

The controller loads the details successfully

The new directive added is

```
  app.directive('mydirective', function(){
        return function(scope, elem, attrs){
        //obtain old header
    var oldHeader = angular.element( '.headerdiv .headerclass' );

    //get the new header

    //replace old header with new header
      }
 });
```

I need to dynamically change the heading in headerdiv with the object.title value . Note that the new directive is bound to the filed that is listening to the object.title div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont think this is the right use of directive, as the directive should be used to affect the functionality of element on which it is defined in most of the cases.

What you can try to do is in `ObjectCtrl` define a watch on title property, and then broadcast the message

```
$scope.$watch('object.title',function(newValue) {
   $rootScope.$broadcast('titleChanged',newValue);  //You can pass any object too
});
```

If you header is contained inside a controller catch the event

```
$scope.$on('titleChanged',function(args) {
    //Code to handle the title update
});
```

The html for header should have binding expression for title

```
<div class="headerdiv">
<h3 class='headerclass'> <a href="">{{title}}</a> </h3>
</div>
```

**Note**: I am not sure about the structure of the html but this all would not be required if the header and the content inside the `ObjectCtrl` are using the same\shared model (object).